# Select Encadeado

Tags: sql

Ola, estou com uma dúvida quanto a um *select* encadeado. Encontrei muitos exemplos com

```
select * from (select campo from tabela)
```

Porém quero definir os campos da minha consulta, como abaixo:

```
select campo1,campo2,(select campo1 from tabela2) from tabela1
```

O ponto é que dentro do *select* preciso de um *where* com uma coluna exibida

```
select campo1,campo2,(select campo1 from tabela2 where id=campo1) from tabela1
```

Como posso indexar a buscar por outra coluna?

Comment: se você não usar o where vai retorna todos os elementos da sua tabela2 o que não é permitido dentro do select, você que realmente ter todos os valores de uma tabela em um campo de um select ?

Comment: vou comentar o caso real, sem exemplos 1 minuto

Comment: acho que o erro é só porque você colocou dois _where_ 

`WHERE TPMOV <> 3 WHERE AG_MTARC.SEQ_TAREFA = AG_MMOV.SEQ_TAREFA`

troca o segundo por `AND`

Comment: Era isso mesmo, vlws! como faço para fechar o post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo nome dos campos acredito que *tabela1* e *tabela2* são a mesma tabela.
Sendo assim você precisa definir um alias para elas pra que o sql consiga diferenciar o campo de uma para outra.

```
SELECT T1.campo1, 
       T1.campo2,
       (select T2.campo1 from tabela2 T2 where T1.id=T2.campo1) as campo3 
FROM tabela1 T1
```

**Editado**

Considerando as informações da resposta abaixo,

```
SELECT T1.id, 
       T1.id venda,
       (select T2.nome from tabela2 T2 where T1.id = T2.id) as nome 
FROM tabela1 T1
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que isso seja possível você precisa ter em mente que a informação do *subselet* precisa retornar apenas um valor. Você não pode retornar dois valores no mesmo alias e poderá receber o erro: `MySQL error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.

```
SELECT 
    cod,
    nome,
    desc,
    (SELECT 
        SUM(dado)
    FROM
        tabela_auxiliar
    WHERE
        cod = 1) as Vendeu,
   (SELECT 
        SUM(dado)
    FROM
        tabela_auxiliar
    WHERE
        cod = 2) as Estocou
FROM
    tabela_principal;
```

No caso da sua "subconsulta" `select campo1 from tabela2 where id=campo1` se tiver retornando dois valores irá ocorrer o erro descrito acima,por este motivo sera um alias para `Estocou` e outro para `Vendeu`.